# Attribute error when importing VLC module in python

Tags: python, vlc, opencv

When i try to run this code :

```
import cv2
import vlc
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
m = vlc.MediaPlayer('D:\faith-42201.mp3')
fd = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\Shivani Khare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2\data\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
m.play()
flag=1
m.audio_set_volume(100)
while(True):
    r,i = cam.read()
    #i[0:10,:,:]=255
    #for adding rows
    j = cv2.cvtColor(i,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face = fd.detectMultiScale(j,1.3,7)
    for (x,y,w,h) in face:
        cv2.rectangle(i,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,0),-1)
        t = w*h
        m.audio_set_volume(100-int(t/500))
        l = len(face)
        if(l>0):
            m.play()
            flag = 0
        elif(flag==0):
            m.pause()
            flag = 1
    print("no of faces are : ",len(face),face)
    cv2.imshow('image1',i)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5)
    print(k)
    if(k==27):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

I keep getting this error :

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Shivani Khare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\hi.py", line 5, in 
    m = vlc.MediaPlayer('D:\faith-42201.mp3')
  File "C:\Users\Shivani Khare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 3184, in **new**
    o.set_media(instance.media_new(*args))
  File "C:\Users\Shivani Khare\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 1788, in media_new
    m._instance = self
AttributeError: **'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instance'**

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a list in MediaPlayer constructor in line#5, but it expects a string(ref: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-play-audio-with-vlc-in-python).

Try making this change:

```
m = vlc.MediaPlayer('D:\faith-42201.mp3')
```

Comment: Thank you @devender22. But I had changed that already, I am still getting the same error. My python version is 3.6.6

Comment: It's working fine in mac env(as file names don't have ":" in them)

In [9]: vlc.MediaPlayer('D:\faith-42201.mp3') # till this point no file is read
Out[9]: <vlc.MediaPlayer at 0x1046abe50>

Can you try to debug this in your m/c like this:
In [5]: import pdb
In [7]: pdb.run('''vlc.MediaPlayer('D:\faith-42201.mp3')''')
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) b <local vlc lib path in your m/c>vlc.py:3184

It has this method media_new which is getting m variable as None. This method treats the file path containing ":" as url path..

Comment: I can try to help if you provide more details what is happening in your env

Comment: Change all of those backslashes to forward slashes, to avoid accidentally mangling strings. Python on Windows will cope with that just fine. it might not be your problems, or it might be causing some internal confusion that's masking your problem.